# How to replace query parameter in URL using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to use regular expressions to replace or append a query to a url with the function adjustUrlParameter(url, param). If the same query exists in the URL, it should replace the query with param (i.e. ID=501 should replace ID=200 in google.com?ID=200). If no query exists, it should simply append the query to the end of the url. Finally, if a query does exist but of a different type, it should append the query and separate it from the pre-existing query with a '&'. Here's an example:

```
adjustUrlParameter('google.com?ID=501', 'TYPE=444') // => 'google.com?ID=501&TYPE=444'
```

My code isn't replacing the same query type. It is returning 'google.com?ID=501&ID=200' instead of returning 'google.com?ID=200'. Here's my code:

```
var adjustUrlParameter = function(url, param) {
  var urlQuery = url.match(/\w+\W+/g);
  for (var i = 0; i < urlQuery.length; i++) {
    if (param === urlQuery[i]) {
        return url.replace(/\?.+$/, '?' + param);
    }
  }

  if (url.match(/\?/)) {
    return url + "&" + param;
  } else {
    return url + "?" + param;
  }

};
```

How do I get adjustUrlParameter('google.com?ID=501', 'ID=201') to return the proper result ('google.com?ID=201')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the if statement never returns true. Put some console.logs in the for loop and watch it. You'll see when urlQuery[i] returns "ID=" param returns "ID=444". They are not equal.

```
console.log("parameter:"+param); //parameter:ID=444
console.log("url_query: "+urlQuery[i]); //url_query: ID=
```

If you change your for loop like below it replaces the query parameter with the same type:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < urlQuery.length; i++) {
    console.log("parameter:"+param);
    console.log("url_query: "+urlQuery[i]);
    var paramType = param.split("="); 
    console.log("paramType"+paramType); 
    var tmp = paramType[0]+"="; //since urlQuery[i] always has a character at the end
    console.log(tmp);
    if (tmp === urlQuery[i]) {
        return url.replace(/\?.+$/, '?' + param);
    }
  }
```

When you run `adjustUrlParameter('google.com?ID=501', 'ID=444')` the output is `"google.com?ID=444"`

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare the names of the queries, not the values they contain too.
Say you pass in `id=200` as `param`, you want to find and replace from `id` in the existing `url`. That means that we don't care about the value of `id`. If that is the case, we can split by `?` or `&` to get a list of all of the queries. We start looping at `2` because `0` and `1` are the base `url` and the `?`. We also jump `2` with every iteration to skip the preceding `&`. Lastly, we make sure to split each `query` with `=` and use `[0]` or the first half to get that name that we care about.

You could do something like this:

```
var adjustUrlParameter = function(url, param) {
    var urlQuery = url.split(/(\?|\&)/)
    ,   thisQuery = param.split(/\=/)[0]
    for (var i = 2; i < urlQuery.length; i = i + 2) {
        if (thisQuery === urlQuery[i].split(/\=/)[0]) {
            return url.replace(/(\?|\&).*$/, '?' + param);
        }
    }

    if (url.match(/\?/)) {
        return url + "&" + param;
    } else {
        return url + "?" + param;
    }

};
```